# How to target a random generated number?

Tags: javascript, html, css, random, generated

I have a script that randomly generates a room id when joined. I want to copy that ID with a click of a button. It would be easy job with a input element, however, I don't know how to even target that random ID to edit and manipulate it. How could I do that?

```js
function createRoom(){

    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = makeid(10);
    roomSelection.add(option);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("arhostas", 1);
}

function makeid(length) {
    var result           = '';
    var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
       result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    return result;
 }
 
 var roomUrl = document.createElement("div");
roomUrl.innerText = `Room id: ${room}`
roomID.append(roomUrl)
```

```html
<div id='roomId'></div>
```

[image]

Room ID is already generated when joined to the room. I just need to copy it to the clipboard somehow. Adding a "createRoom" code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`room_id_div` is not a valid html-element. You can create an element and assign some properties to it in one go using `Object.assign`. If you want to use the id within the `innerText` of the created element, you'll have to create the (random) id separately.

Alternatively you can set the content of a div using a pseudo-selector in css (`:before`). In that case you don't need to create a random id separately. The downside is that the text within the div can not be selected (hence, not copied to the clipboard).

Both demonstrated in this snippet:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", handle);
document.addEventListener("change", handle);

function handle(evt) {
  const origin = evt.target;
  if (/Room$/.test(origin.id)) {
    return origin.id === "fromIdRoom" ? 
      createRoom1() : createRoom2();
  } else if (origin.id === "roomSelector") {
    if (origin.value !== "-1") {
      document.querySelectorAll("#roomId1 div")
        .forEach(elem => elem.style.backgroundColor = "");
      document.querySelector(`#${origin.value}`).style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFC0";
    }
  }
}

// room id from css pseudo :before
// use [makeId] directly
function createRoom1() {
  const roomParent = document.querySelector("#roomId1");
  roomParent.append(
    Object.assign(
      document.createElement("div"), {
        id: `X${makeId(15)}`, // NOTE: id can not start with a number
      })
  );
  const idNow = roomParent.querySelector("div:last-child").id;
  roomParent.querySelector("select").append(
    Object.assign(
      document.createElement("option"), {
        value: idNow,
        textContent: idNow
      })
  );
}

// room id within innerText
// you'll need to pre-assign [room]
function createRoom2() {
  const room = `X${makeId(15)}`; // NOTE: id can not start with a number
  document.querySelector("#roomId2").append(
    Object.assign(
      document.createElement("div"), {
        id: room,
        innerText: `Room id: ${room}`,
      })
  );
}

function makeId(length) {
  var result = '';
  var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
  var charactersLength = characters.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
  }
  return result;
}
```

```css
#roomId1 div:before {
  content: 'Room id from css: 'attr(id);
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button id="fromIdRoom">create create a room within #roomId1</button>
  <button id="createRoom">create a room within #roomId2</button>

</p>
<div id='roomId1'>
  <select id="roomSelector">
    <option value="-1">Select room</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id='roomId2'></div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I might be doing something wrong. I added my "createRoom" code. Could you please take a look? My room is generated beforehand.

Comment: There's not enough context in your code to say much about it. It seems that you want to add a rooms id to a `<select>` element?

Comment: Well, that script creates a room with a random generated number (on different html file). Now I want to copy that number with a click of a button as you showed. But your code generates that random code and then copies it. I will accept your answer regardless.

Comment: Ok, not completely clear to me, but I hope it helped you further along. Added demo functionality for a 'roomselector' just to be sure, but it may well be that's not what you intended.

Comment: NB: for creating random strings/-html-id's you may be interested in `randomStringExtension` within [this helper library](https://github.com/KooiInc/DOM-Utilities/blob/master/SmallHelpers.js)

Answer (score 0):

The `navigator.clipboard` API is the modern method for copying to the clipboard [navigator.clipboard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API). The tab must be active for you to copy to the clipboard for security reasons. So you can't copy the id in this snippet

You created an element `room_id_div` that isn't a valid HTML element. So I changed it to a normal `div` tag.

I created a `button` to listen for click and then copy the text.

```js
const length = 7;
const button = document.getElementById('copyId');
const roomID = document.getElementById('roomId');
const roomUrl = document.createElement("div");

function makeId(length) {
  let result = '';
  const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
  const charactersLength = characters.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
  }

  return result;
}

button.addEventListener('click', _ => {
  roomID.innerHTML = '';
  const id = makeId(length);
  navigator.permissions.query({
    name: "clipboard-write"
  }).then(permission => {
    if (permission.state == 'granted') navigator.clipboard.writeText(id).then(_ => alert('Successfully copied to clipboard!!'), _ => alert('Error copying id to clipboard'));
    else alert('Error copying id to clipboard');
  });

  roomUrl.innerText = `Room id: ${id}`;
  roomID.append(roomUrl);
});
```

```html
<div id='roomId'></div>
<button id="copyId">Generate and Copy Id</button>
```

Comment: That looks great, however, I already have a generated room number, I just need to copy it. Maybe somehow make that ID appear in an input element.